# How to run .exe file with button click?

Tags: c#

i want to use auth system for my app. i found auth.gg . after login I want to run my app with button click.
i found this.

```
    // string str = @"C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe";

   // string str  = @"C:\windows\system32\winamp.exe";


    string str  = @"C:\Documents and Settings\Puru\Desktop\NewsLetter\SendNewsletter.exe";
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = str;
    process.Start();
```

but if i try to run on different computer location wont be same.

and i found this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Application.StartupPath\\example.exe");
```

and i didnt understand this. Where should i locate example.exe?

after all i want to make,
1-user will run auth
2-after pass auth system will click button and second .exe file will open

Comment: "Documents and Settings"? You do know Windows XP has been end of life since 2013, right? As in, no security patches for more than 7 years now? As in, really, **really** unsafe to still be using?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Auth.gg, you should have a class for it where you initialize the constants and then use a function to login. This can be done from within the application, so my question to you is, why are you doing it from an external application? Best practice would be to have the login in the same executable.

If you so dearly want to do it from an external program, you could always use what you supplied.

You should then use it like so:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Application.StartupPath\\example.exe"); // Folder containing your program, where example.exe is located
```

So you can place "example.exe" in the same folder as the application you just ran for the login. Replace "example.exe" with the name + extension of your other program that login is supposed to launch.

Comment: i located a png to same folder but it didnt work. can i merge this files? because i want to use it on different computers. and i want to use one file.